# Making my table look better

Tags: tables

Here's my code:

```
\textbf{Table 1. Key DAQmx VIs}
            \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
                \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Icon} & \textbf{Description}\\ \hline
                 Create Channel & \includegraphics[width=2in]{createchannel.png} & This VI will create virtual channels and adds them to a task. An example of inputs can be \textbf{physical channels} for analog input/output. For the analog input/output a max and min value inputs are used to optimize measurements as it restricts the input readings to the expected values. In our case, the VI is used to take the analog voltage input from analog input 0 (as seen on the front panel in Figure 5, 6, or 7) and the task is sent out.\\ \hline
                Timing & \includegraphics[width=2in]{timing.png} & \\ \hline
                Read & \includegraphics[width=2in]{read.png} & \\ \hline
                Write & \includegraphics[width=2in]{write.png} & \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \end{center}
```

Here's my output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: if you indent lines of code by four spaces -- most easily accomplished by highlighting the lines in question and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the edit window -- the site software will pretty-print the material automatically.

Comment: BTW, the `tabular` environment does *not* take an argument that specifies the desired overall width. LaTeX should be throwing an error when it encounters `\begin{tabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the possibility of a pagebreak then load package `ltablex` and
do *not*  the environmant `table`. See documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright,
       singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][]{\raisebox{\dimexpr0.75\normalbaselineskip-\height}{%
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Key DAQmx VIs}\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|X|}\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Icon} & \textbf{Description}\\ \hline
Create Channel & \Includegraphics[width=2in]{createchannel.png} 
         & This VI will 
create virtual channels and adds them to a task. An example of inputs can be 
    \textbf{physical channels} for analog input/output. For the analog 
            input/output a max and min value inputs are used to optimize measurements as 
            it restricts the input readings to the expected values. In our case, the VI is 
            used to take the analog voltage input from analog input 0 (as seen on the 
            front panel in Figure 5, 6, or 7) and the task is sent out.\\ \hline
Timing & \Includegraphics[width=2in]{timing.png} & \\ \hline
Read & \Includegraphics[width=2in]{read.png} & \\ \hline
Write & \Includegraphics[width=2in]{write.png} & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

similarly to [Herbert's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/herbert) answer, but with use of `adjustbox` and different selection of column types and selected ratios between theirs widths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\insertimage[1]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt,valign=t]{#1}
                           }

\begin{document}
\textbf{Table 1. Key DAQmx VIs}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
                                 |p{50mm}
                                 |>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|}
    \hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Icon} & \textbf{Description}\\ \hline
Create Channel
    &   \insertimage{createchannel.png}
        &   This VI will create virtual channels and adds them to a task. 
            An example of inputs can be \textbf{physical channels} for 
            analog input/output. For the analog input/output a max and min 
            value inputs are used to optimize measurements as it restricts 
            the input readings to the expected values. In our case, the VI 
            is used to take the analog voltage input from analog input 0 (as 
            seen on the front panel in Figure 5, 6, or 7) and the task is 
            sent out.\\ \hline
Timing
    &   \insertimage{timing.png}
        &       \\ \hline
Read
    &   \insertimage{read.png}
        &       \\ \hline
Write
    &   \insertimage{write.png}
        &       \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]